# DirectShow SDK vs DirectX SDK

Tags: video-streaming, directx, directshow, directshow.net

I will like to develop a desktop app under WIndows 10 to manipulate a USB camera and capture frames for image processing. I will like to stay within a Windows framework but there many options.  The one that trouble me is choosing the correct technology.   What is the difference between DirectShow SDK and DirectX SDK if any within W10 development?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The short answer: Don't use either of them. Use the standard Windows SDK.**

Both the DirectShow SDK and the DirectX SDK are deprecated. I think the last standalone DirectShow SDK was somewhere in the mid 1990s after which the DirectShow APIs started shipping in the DirectX SDK.

The DirectX SDK is now end-of-life with the last release from June 2010, but DirectShow was removed from the legacy DirectX SDK in 2005. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-). DirectShow is legacy, but is still available in the standard Windows SDK.

The modern solution for video work on Windows is [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk) which is part of the standard Windows SDK. Video capture support was added in Windows 7. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/whats-new-for-media-foundation)

You should also see [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediasdkstuff/)

> One more note: If you plan to create an application that uses Media Foundation or DirectShow, you should be sure to read up on handling [Windows N Editions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/08/13/who-moved-my-windows-media-cheese/).